# Css selector when sibling has a property

Tags: html, css, selector

Is it possible to include "sibling" in css selector?

Case:

1)

```
<div>
  <textarea/>
  <input/>
</div>
```

2)

```
<div>
  <textarea/>
  <input style="display:none;"/>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
div > texarea {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  bottom-padding: 20px;
  ....
}
div > input {
  bottom: 0px;
  ....
}
```

In both cases I want textarea fits the parent div. But in first case input should be at the bottom of the div, So I use bottom-padding. How to be in second case?

Comment: You want CSS to also detect placement? (Which came first?)

Comment: Please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS currently dosen't support styling parents based on some condition of it's child(s).

I suggest you put a class on your parent DIV based on whats in it, and style the DIV based on that class.

Comment: I'm thinking about how to apply some style to "texarea" when sibling "input" has some property, for example, display: none.